# Given $A \subset U$ and $B \subset U$. Prove or disprove $A - B \ = \emptyset \implies A \subset B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Given $A \subset U$ and $B \subset U$. Prove or disprove $A - B \ = \emptyset \implies A \subset B$

I think this is the way to do it: $$ A = B \implies A \subset B \implies A' = B' \implies A-B = \emptyset  $$

Comment: It's false. Suppose $U=\{1,2\}, A=\{1\}, B=\{2\}$. Your "proof" makes no sense: you start from the premise $A=B$, but wherever does that come from? The next implication is wrong too: $A\subset B$ does not imply $A'=B'$, assuming prime means complement. And anyway it seems you're trying to prove the wrong direction.

Comment: @BrianO sorry for answering to a very old comment, but isn't your counterexample incorrect? While it is true that $\{1\} \not\subset \{2\}$, we have $\{1\} \setminus \{2\} =\{1\}$, which is not $\emptyset$ and so it doesn't serve as a counterexample for the statement above. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Frieren you’re right. The statement is true, actually, but the proof is ridiculous/not a proof. $A\setminus B = \emptyset$ means there’s no $x$ with $x\in A \land x\notin B$. But that’s equivalent to: for all $x$, if $x\in A$ then $x\in B$ — which is to say, $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: My A and B arent counterexamples to the thing OP is trying yo prove, but they are counterexamples to the “reasoning” shown.

Comment: @BrianO: Thanks for the reply, now I see what you meant.

Comment: No problem, thanks back. If you think my original comment is confusing I’ll happily delete it.